# C#: How can you regulate a windows form to only allow to be resized by width and not by height?

Tags: c#

C#: How can you regulate a windows form to only allow to be resized by width and not by height?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`MinimumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize(VS.80).aspx) and [`MaximumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize(VS.80).aspx) properties.  Set the minimum height equal to the maximum height.  No code required.

Comment: Totally forgot about that property. Thank you.